# How do I conditionally change a prop element's style (background color) in react js?

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, conditional-statements, react-props

I have a parent and child components that I use to display some contents about Inventory reports using react props. basically, the props contain information about individual inventory report card and one of those props is a tag that could have a "weekly", "monthly" or "yearly" value. I would like to dynamically change the background of each tag based on the text. So for example. if the tag = "daily", the background of the tag element should be black, if tag="monthly" background should be red and if tag=yearly, the background should be able. Note that I only want to change the background of the tag element and I have a color scss file where I have stored different color variables whichIi want to use to accomplish the change mentioned above.

THE CARD COMPONENT CODE (child component)

```
<>
            {props.details.map((value, index) => (
                <div className='report-container' key={index}>
                    <div className="report-header">
                        <h1>{value.title}</h1>
                        <p className="date">{value.creation_date}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="tag-container">
                        <span className="tag"> {value.tag} </span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="report-card-deets">
                        <p className="file-size"> {value.file_size} </p>
                        <button>Download</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
            ;
        </>
```

MY ARRAY containing values that will be populated in the card component

```
const ReportData = [
    {
        title: "Inventory Turnover report",
        creation_date: "31-03-2023",
        tag: "Daily",
        file_size: "100 kb",
    },
    {
        title: "Top ordered items report",
        creation_date: "28-03-2023",
        tag: "Yearly",
        file_size: "203 kb",
    },
    {
        title: "Stockout rate report",
        creation_date: "01-04-2023",
        tag: "Weekly",
        file_size: "400 mb",
    },
];
```

MY COLOR VARIABLES

```
$primary-color: #1F8A70;
$secondary-color: #68B984;
$tertiary-color: #D6DCD8;
$text-color: #000000;
$text-color-light: white;
$background-color: #EDE4E0;
$container-background: #F2E9E5;
$table-background: #1F8A70;
$card-gradient: linear-gradient(285.25deg, #92C1A2 30.98%, rgba(107, 175, 109, 0.43) 77.71%);
$background-gradient: conic-gradient(from 126.2deg at 50% 50%, #1F8A70 0deg, rgba(76, 167, 124, 0.54) 178.12deg, rgba(103, 184, 132, 0.278471) 295.36deg, #1F8A70 360deg);
```

I already tried inline conditioning but that is not recommended since I have 3 conditions rather than 2. Also, I was wondering if I would be able to do this with className but I haven't quite figured that out at this moment. What would you recommend guys?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [styled-component](https://styled-components.com/) library to create components from html tags. In your case, this code would solve the problem:

First, you need create the styled-component:

```
const DynamicBackground = styled.div`
  background-color: ${ props => 
                  props.tag === 'Daily' ? 'red' 
                  : props.tag === 'Yearly' ? 'blue'
                  : 'green'
              }
`
```

This component can recive the tag prop and its ready to use in the CardComponent. It will looks like:

```
return (
    <>
      {props.details.map((value, index) => (
          ...
          <DynamicBackground tag={value.tag} />
          ...
      ))}
      ;
   </>
  )
```

Comment: Hello Alejandro. This works, however only the colors show, the value of tag props does not appear at all

Answer (score 0):

Changing the child component code to the following will fix the props value not showing:

`<DynamicBackground className='tag' tag={value.tag} > {value.tag} </DynamicBackground>`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the Styled component as @Alejandro suggested, you can use this approach:

```
<>
{props.details.map((value, index) => (
    <div
        className='report-container'
        key={index}
        style={{
            backgroundColor: value.tag === 'Weekly' ? 'red' // you may use your preferred color hexadecimal instead (ex: #f00)
                : value.tag === 'Monthly' ? 'blue' // you may use your preferred color hexadecimal instead (#00f)
                    : 'green' // you may use your preferred color hexadecimal instead (#0f0)
        }}>
        <div className="report-header">
            <h1>{value.title}</h1>
            <p className="date">{value.creation_date}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="tag-container">
            <span className="tag"> {value.tag} </span>
        </div>
        <div className="report-card-deets">
            <p className="file-size"> {value.file_size} </p>
            <button>Download</button>
        </div>
    </div>
))}
</>
```

**Note:** I'm assuming that `Weekly`, `Monthly` and `Yearly` are the only values that `value.tag` will hold, if it will hold any additional values like Daily, you will need to add it to the conditional part.

Comment: Thanks mate. This solution is quite easy and well explained !